# Running a shell from Node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to run a shell(scala shell) from nodejs. Basically, I want an interactive scala shell running in the background to which I can pass input and get a response from it. I have looked into child process in nodejs documentation but I was not able to make it work. 
I have tried exec like shown below.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('scala');

child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('from child', data.toString());
});

child.stdin.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('Stdin received', data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('from child error', data.toString());
});
```

When I run the program, the child takes input from stdin (anything I type) character by character. I want to send strings to the child and get a response from it. So passing scala code like "val a = 0;" will return "a: Int = 0" from the scala shell.

I tried spawn function of the child process but it gives me an error.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
child = spawn('scala');

Error: spawn scala ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:592:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code example and it works for me.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
child = spawn('scala');

child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('from child', data.toString());
});

child.stdin.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('Stdin received', data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('from child error', data.toString());
});
```

.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

The error ENOENT indicates that node is not able to find scala. Ensure that scala is available in path or provide absolute path to the binary.

Comment: Great, thanks. I am using windows and scala is in my path. I also included absolute path but it did not work.  However,  I tried it on Ubuntu and it works. I will see if I can figure out what was the problem with windows.